# SQL Syntax help -- auto increament

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT )
```

The above command increases id from 0 ,but i want to increase it from a specific no. say like 1234567890  ..

how can i do that??

How can i set auto increment from a specific no.??

I tried something like this but it did not work

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1234567890, (id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT)
```

If the question is not clear pllzz comment..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
)
ENGINE = MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1234567890;
```

**Edit:** A quick note with regards to storage engine support for setting the AUTO_INCREMENT value, which will depend on the version of MySQL you're running.

From [MySQL 5.0 Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html),

> In MySQL 5.0, this works for MyISAM
>   and MEMORY tables. It is also
>   supported for InnoDB as of MySQL
>   5.0.3.

From [MySQL 5.1 Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html),

> In MySQL 5.1, this works for MyISAM,
>   MEMORY, and InnoDB tables. It also
>   works for ARCHIVE tables as of MySQL
>   5.1.6.

Comment: +1 Nice, didn't realize you could do it in the `create` as well.

Answer (score 4):

After your create table script, use the alter table syntax to update the auto_increment value:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the table:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create your table like your first statement, then add

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1234567890;
```

...where 1234567890 is ofc the value you want the value. More details can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html